# Difference between family name, name at birth and first names?

Tags: names

I'm filling an English document and I'm being asked to complete my family name, then my name at birth and then my first names. Does anyone know the difference between these 3 concepts? My guess is that my family name is my last name, my name at birth is my complete name at birth, and my first names are everything but my surname. Is that correct?

Comment: You should really inquire with the agency that created (or will process) the form.

Comment: Is it really plural first ***names*** on the form??

Comment: @Jim, yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the common usage of those terms but for a specific form check with whoever is asking for the form to be filled out.

**Family name** is the part of the name you share with your family, often called "last name" or "surname" in English (though that's less accurate since some cultures put the family name first).

**Name at birth** would be your full-name on your birth certificate (usually the same unless you've changed your name).

**First Name** is your given name (strange to see a form that mixes "first name" and "family name") if it says first names (plural) it might include all other names other than your family name (eg middle names).

Comment: First name**s** includes those also called *middle names* - basically all names in order except for family name. Also, some people actually go by their first middle name, so First Name isn't necessarily the given name. So they might have Paul as their Firstname, but David as (one of) their middle names, used as their given name. In short, everyone might be different ¬_¬

Comment: Name at birth implies *Maiden Name* or even name before you changed it at some point.

Comment: @DavidM that'd be the most common reason to change your name but people change names for reasons other than women who get married so "Maiden name" doesn't cover all of it.

Comment: @Mike not disagreeing with your answer. Expanding upon it.

Answer (score 2):

"name at birth" is probably *family name* (last name, surname) *at birth*, as some people change their family name on marriage.

I don't think it would expect your *full name at birth* in that box, at least in the UK - but does the length of the box give any indication?

Answer (score 0):

They are attempting (poorly in my opinion) to come up with a way of getting full accurate name information that would apply cross culturally. In some cultures, the concept of "first name" is different than other cultures, especially those where the family name is said first, FOLLOWED by the given name. In some religions, you have a "birth name" but also a "Christian name" given to you at Baptism or Confirmation. Different again is the fact that some families will have official "first names" on the birth certificates, but everyone inside of the family uses what others would consider "middle" names. My wife's family from South Dakota was like that; her mother's name was Virginia, but everyone in the family called her Fay. Her aunt's name was Nancy, but everyone called her Ruth. In both cases those were their middle names. Confused the heck out of me until my wife explained it.